# Linear dependence of a set vs a family of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, modules

In one of my lectures, after defining linear dependence as such:

Let R be a ring and M an R-module. A finite family $(x_i)_{i=1, ..., n}$ of elements in M are called linearly dependent if there exists $(a_i)_{i=1, ..., n}$ in R, not all zero, such that $a_1x_1 + ... +a_nx_n = 0$.

They followed it with a remark:

If a family contains repetition, it is linearly dependent: Indeed, if $x_{i_0}=x_{i_1}$ with $i_0<i_1$ then take $a_i$ such that

- $a_i=0 \text{ for } I \notin \{i_0, i_1\}$
- $a_{i_0} = 1 \text{ and } a_{i_1} = -1$

Together with the above definition, this makes sense mathematically. However, intuitively it does not, since I imagine two linearly dependent vectors in, say for example, 2 dimensions as on the same line. With this, if you have two linearly independent vectors, and just add the first one again to the family, suddenly they're all linearly dependent? How does this make sense intuitively?

I think my confusion here lies with the concept of a "family". Since in a set there are no repeats, this problem wouldn't occur. So why is linear dependence different for a set and a family, if they have the same elements and the family only has a few repeats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're thinking of linear dependence / independence as a property of the individual vectors, but it's a property of the family of vectors.

If you've got a bowl of M&Ms that are all different colors-- say, red, blue, and yellow-- you might call it an "all different colors" bowl of M&Ms. But if you put another blue M&M in the bowl, now you don't have an "all different colors" bowl of M&Ms anymore. It's not that the individual M&Ms now lack the "all different colors" property, it's that the bowl does.

Similarly, if you've got a family of linearly independent vectors, and you add a duplicate, it's not the vectors that become linearly dependent, it's the family of vectors that becomes linearly dependent.

Comment: I like M&Ms and your analogy; $+1$

Comment: The analogy with the m&m's is incredibly helpful! I thought about linear dependence more like "all m&m's in the bowl are the same color", so if only one is another color, the whole bowl would become "linearly independent". But yes I see now it's rather the other way around. 

Does the same thing however apply to a set of vectors? Say you have a set of linearly independent vectors and you add one random vector that is linearly dependent to a single vector of the original set. Does the whole set then become linearly dependent?

Comment: Yes. Taking the notation from your remark, you may set $a_{i_1}=-\lambda$ if $x_{i_0}=\lambda x_{i_1}$ and the rest as above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm more familiar with the vector space setting, but intuitively speaking, linear independence means that the family of vectors is minimal out of all families of vectors with the same span. That is, if you remove any single vector from the family, you'll reduce the span.

For example, two linearly independent vectors will span a plane, but removing either of the vectors will reduce the span to a single line. This makes them linearly independent. We can easily find three vectors to span a plane, but inevitably we only really need two of the vectors; one of the three can be safely removed, and the remaining two vectors will span the same plane.

If you have a family of vectors with repetitions, then removing repetitions can never damage the span, so instantly this precludes the family from remaining linearly independent.

You can also think about it in terms of null linear combinations. If $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is a family of vectors with $v_1 = v_2$, then
$$1v_1 + (-1)v_2 + 0 v_3 + \ldots + 0 v_n = 0$$
is a non-trivial linear combination. If you prefer to think of one vector as a linear combination of the others, then $v_1 = 1v_2 + 0v_3 + \ldots + 0v_n$ is such a relationship.

From every which way, it makes sense for repeated vectors to be linearly dependent.